# XNA SkyBox In WP7 Silverlight Application

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I need to create skybox in windows phone.
I have windows phone silverlight application, and want to add an XNA SkyBox as separate page.

Can anyony provide a good working example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add XNA rendering to an already existing Silverlight application, you can do that easily, just follow [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221583.aspx) on MSDN.

You also have an option to create new project from a project template that already mixes Silverlight and XNA. If your application is new, maybe you could start from scratch instead of extending the application.

Comment: thanks Toni for this msdn instrucions. Now how to add skybox there? ;) ... I need to figure it out somehow...

Comment: Well, that is whole another topic :)

Comment: I assumed that you can google for it and check the links you get. It is not a short answer. What seemed more important aspect of your question is how to add another XNA page. Then all it takes for you is to get any skybox tutorial you find out there and copy/paste the code in that newly created page. Surely you can do that.